# Ftp script file error

Tags: java, batch-file, ftp

I am trying to download some files via a ftpscript.bat file using Java.

the script in the file is as below.

`open 122.22.11.111
Tempuser
Temppass
get 'TEMPDATA.TEXT.INPUT'
bye`

The code works well in C drive. But this goes to below error in D drive at any location.

**Error** opening script file script.bat.Transfers files to and from a computer running an FTP server service(sometimes called a daemon). Ftp can be used interactively.FTP [-v] [-d] [-i] [-n] [-g] ...

I am trying to access the script file using ProcessBuilder in java.

```
path = "D:\MyFiles"

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "cd \"" + path + "\" && ftp -s:ftpscript.bat");
```

Comment: `ProcessBuilder("myCommand", "myArg1", "myArg2");` see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, use Java library for FTP. Do not drive an external console application! See [How to download file from FTP using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28873802/850848)

---

Anyway, your problem is that `cd D:\MyFiles` does not change drive, you have to use

```
cd /D D:\MyFiles
```

See [Using cd command in Windows command line, can't navigate to D:](https://superuser.com/q/135214/213663)

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. But it still did not work.                               
        C:\>cd /D D:\MyFiles & FTP -S:SCRIPT.BAT

Transfers files to and from a computer running an FTP server service
(sometimes called a daemon). Ftp can be used interactively.

Comment: It's `-s` (as you have it in your question), not `-S`