# Some downloaded files are missing bytes (Apache Commons FTPClient)

Tags: java, android, download, ftp, apache-commons

This is a continuation of my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62023585/2016165) because I noticed that other file types are affected too (not only images).

My Android app (Java 8, min SDK 24, target SDK 27) downloads images (jpg,png) and text files (txt) from an FTP server, using Apache Common's `FTPClient` (version 3.6).

**The problem:**

A certain percentage of these files are missing bytes and it seems to be pretty random too:

1. If I download the files from a Win 10 server in the same network, about 50% of the files are missing up to 30 bytes (images, for text files it's usually 1-2 bytes).
2. If I download the files from a Linux server in the same network, usually only 1-2 files (out of 10) are affected and even the affected images are usually only missing 1-2 bytes. Rarely no files "fail" at all.

The text files don't seem to be affected much by the missing bytes but the images are all the more. Depending on how many bytes are missing in the end, they can be visibly corrupted: From missing/transparent rows at the bottom of the images (1-2 bytes) to completely messed up colors or artifacts in the bottom half of the image (>2 bytes missing).

I also tested my code with two other servers that aren't within the same network:

3. A private server (no idea if Win or Linux): It's really buggy and the connection often just drops while uploading files, plus it automatically deletes files once an hour, so I've not been able to do a lot of testing but so far no downloaded files have been affected.
4. [DLP Test](https://dlptest.com/ftp-test/): The uploaded files are deleted after 15 or 30 minutes, so I can't run any long tests but so far the downloaded files have all been okay.

For testing I created a completely fresh project. I use images I created myself (sorry, can't share these) and random images that I found on google - they're between 12kb (which always download completely) and about 8mb each. You can find an album of these images (and corrupted sample downloads) [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0r4uR.jpg). The txt files I created myself (sorry, can't share these either) are about 14mb each.

My suspicion is: Files are downloaded much faster from within the same network than from an outside server, so maybe the faster download causes "hiccups" that skip a couple of bytes. But then, why would it only affect the ones at the end?

**My code** (no exception handling as it would be too long):

```
private boolean login() {
    try {
        ftpClient.connect(url,port);
        if(ftpClient.isConnected()) {
            if(ftpClient.login(username,password)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Ignoring this for now
    }
    return false;
}

private void logout() {
    if(ftpClient!=null && ftpClient.isConnected()) {
        try {
            ftpClient.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //Ignoring this for now
        }
    }
}

public void downloadFiles(final String remoteFolder, final String localFolder, final ArrayList<String> filenames) {
    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak") AsyncTask asyncTask = new AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) {
            if(login()) {
                //Comment for version 1:
                //In my actual code (with error handling) I create the OutputStream 
                //object here, so I can close it in "finally" but I still open a new 
                //one for every file:
                //FileOutputStream out = null;
                try {
                    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
                    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);

                    if(ftpClient.changeWorkingDirectory(remoteFolder)) {
                        for (String filename : filenames) {
                            FTPFile[] singleFile = ftpClient.listFiles(filename);

                            if (singleFile != null && singleFile.length > 0) { //check if the file exists
                                String localPath = localFolder + File.separator + filename;

                                /////////////// Version 1 ///////////////
                                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(localPath);

                                if (!ftpClient.retrieveFile(filename, out)) {
                                    out.close();
                                    break;
                                }

                                out.close();

                                //Only for version 1:
                                File ff = new File(localPath);
                                long remoteLength = singleFile[0].getSize();
                                long newLength = ff.length();

                                if(newLength<remoteLength) {
                                    Log.d(TAG,filename+" - should be: "+remoteLength+" / is: "+newLength);
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG,filename+" - OKAY");
                                }

                                //For version 2 & 3:
                                /*FTPFile single = singleFile[0];
                                long remoteLength = single.getSize();
                                InputStream is = ftpClient.retrieveFileStream(filename);
                                int len;
                                byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) (remoteLength)];
                                int newLength = 0;

                                /////////////// Version 2 ///////////////
                                BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

                                while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
                                    if(len>0) {
                                        newLength += len;
                                        out.write(buffer,0,len);
                                    } else {
                                        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(500));
                                    }
                                }
                                bis.close();

                                /////////////// Version 3 ///////////////
                                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                                while ((len = is.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)) != -1) {
                                    baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
                                    newLength += len;
                                }

                                baos.flush();

                                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(localPath);
                                fos.write(baos.toByteArray());
                                fos.flush();
                                fos.close();
                                is.close();

                                //For version 2 & 3:    
                                ftpClient.completePendingCommand();

                                if(newLength<remoteLength) {
                                    Log.d(TAG,filename+" - should be: "+remoteLength+" / is: "+newLength);
                                } else {
                                    Log.d(TAG,filename+" - OKAY");
                                }*/
                            } else {
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //Ignoring this for now
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param) {
            logout();
        }
    };
    asyncTask.execute();
}
```

There aren't any exceptions/errors in my version with full exception handling.

Version 1 seems to have the highest success rate (about 1/20 files are missing bytes) and there doesn't seem to be a difference between version 2 und version 3.

One thing I did noticed: The smaller `buffer` is (version 2 & 3), the more files are downloaded completely from server 1. With a size of e.g. 1000 only 1-3 files are missing bytes but with 100000 it's about half that "fail". The buffer size doesn't seem to affect server 2 much though, or at least it isn't noticable because the success rate is already pretty high.

**Question:**

Am I missing anything in my code or am I doing something wrong? What could be causing bytes to simply not "download"? Hence: What can I do to fix this problem?

Comment: Please start by using a more standard download code for your tests – See [How to download file from FTP using Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28873802/850848).

Comment: So version 1 with a `FileOutputStream` instead of the `OutputStream` (AndroidTeam's answer)?

Comment: Yes, `FTPClient.retrieveFile` with `FileOutputStream`.

Comment: Okay, just did: The first run on server #1 went perfect, the second on server #2 gave me 3 messed up files (out of 13): 2 pngs (same image but different name) and a txt file are missing 1 byte each. Sorry, I forgot to write that there's one difference between the code above and mine: In mine `FileOutputStream out = null;` is in the line after `if(login())`, so I can close it in my `finally` (if necessary) but I still open a new one for every file, so hopefully that shouldn't make too much of a difference (I added it in the code above).

Comment: Please edit your question to show the simplest possible code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Dont use an intermediate ByteArrayOutputStream. You can write the bytes directly to the FileOutputStream.

Comment: I dont see you logging and comparing the values of remoteLength and newLength. Nor did you inform us.

Comment: Indeed do not make that buffer the size of remoteLength.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It's version 1, the rest is commented out now.

Comment: @blackapps Ad comment 1: Using the `ByteArrayOutputStream` is just one version. There are 3 and they all produce the error at some point. If you want to test it, pick any you like but I'd recommend version 2/3 to see the error quicker. ;) Ad comment 2: There's a `Log.d` at the bottom for version 2/3 and I just added one for version 1 too. `Nor did you inform us` - What do you mean? Ad comment 3: Making the buffer size `remoteLength` is a good way to check if the problem's still there. Just because the success rate with a smaller one is 90%, doesn't make it a working solution I can use/rely on.

Comment: @blackapps Addition to comment 1: At the very beginning version 2 (the one that writes directly to `FileOutputStream`) only used an `InputStream` instead of that + the `BufferedInputStream` but I added the latter when I noticed the problem, trying to fix it with that. It doesn't seem to make a difference though.

Comment: `I dont see you logging and comparing the values of remoteLength and newLength. Nor did you inform us. `.

Comment: @blackapps The comparison for version 2 & 3 was there from the beginning and I added code for that for version 1 less than an hour ago.  `Nor did you inform us.` - What did I not inform you of?

Comment: You did not tell us if newLength became equal to remoteLength. Or if the difference was already those two bytes there too.

Comment: At the moment it only matters if the new file is smaller than the file on the server (= the original file) because only then the problem occurs. It's never given me a new file that was bigger than the original, so I combined that case with "same size". Plus, the remote file has only got a limited amount of bytes that it can loop through, so the local file should never be bigger than the original anyway. I checked the size of the files on the server after uploading them and it's the same as the original, so something about the download process has to drop the missing bytes.

Comment: Btw, the difference betwen `newLength` and `remoteLength` isn't always "2". Sometimes 0 bytes are missing, sometimes it's 1 and sometimes it might be 20. It seems to be pretty random which files are affected and how many bytes are missing. I only noticed that certain versions of my code in combination with a certain servers are more likely to cause the problem to occur than others. I wrote about that in my question though and shared all of my findings.

Comment: Did you test the download using a (GUI/commandline) client running on the same machine as your Java code?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Sorry for the late reply! You mean, use something like Filezilla to download files from server 1 or 2 on the same PC I develop the Android app on? Yes, I've been using that app to upload the files to the servers and also just tested downloading the files multiple times: Everything looks fine, no weird artifacts and no missing bytes.

Comment: Any idea/suggestion what else I could try to fix this problem?

Comment: I tested the same code in ASCII mode today and the downloaded files are missing bytes too (about 66% success rate with server 1).

Comment: Update: I tried replacing the `AsyncTask` with a normal `Thread` but the problem was still there with the first 2 servers. I then wrote my own small library for login/logout & download using Java's default `Socket` (so without using Apache's library) but no luck with that either. I also ran my library (but with a `SwingWorker` instead of `AsyncTask`) as a normal Windows app with a `JFrame` and a `JButton` and tested it about 30 times with different files: None of them was missing even a single byte. It looks like this is a problem with Android, sockets and servers in the same network. :/